# Simple importance sampling example: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, importance-sampling

I am learning about importance sampling and trying undertake importance sampling on a trivial example, but failing to get the right answer. I have read various PDFs online, and the relevant section of *Tools for Statistical Inference* by Tanner, but it just isn't clicking with me. I have found other questions here on importance sampling confusing, particularly the weights. I have fleshed out my thinking as carefully as possible below, so that hopefully where I'm going wrong is clear (the weights, I believe).

The example is as follows: I have some data (16 data points, say), $Y$, that I assume have come from a Normal distribution with unknown parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

I choose the priors

$\sigma^2 \sim LogNormal(-1.83, 0.25)$

(for reasons related to my work) and

$\mu \sim N(\bar{y}, 4s^2)$, where

$\bar{y}$ and $s^2$ are the mean and variance of $y$.

I chose this prior for $\mu$ because it will resemble the data, but have a heavier tail.

To estimate the mean and variance of the distribution of the data, I believe that I should take draws from $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and weight them. To estimate $\mu$, I should find

$\frac{\Sigma_i^{n} \mu_i w_i}{\Sigma_i^n w_i}$, where $n$ is the number of draws.

The weight is where I believe I'm going wrong. My numerator is the posterior, i.e. the priors multiplied by the likelihood:

$\begin{aligned} w_i &\propto \frac{priors * likelihood}{\text{density I simulated from}}\\
  & = \frac{P(\sigma^2)P(\mu)\prod_{j=1}^{16} \frac{1}{\sigma}\phi \left(\frac{y_j-\mu}{\sigma} \right)}{P(\sigma^2)\frac{1}{2s}\phi \left(\frac{\mu - \bar{y}}{2s} \right)}
\end{aligned}$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are draws from the priors. The priors for $\sigma^2$ cancel, but what of $P(\mu)$? I have removed it as a constant of proportionality, but I'm not sure if that's correct. Doing this leaves me with

$\begin{aligned} w_i &\propto \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{16} \frac{1}{\sigma}\phi \left(\frac{y_j-\mu}{\sigma} \right)}{\frac{1}{2s}\phi \left(\frac{\mu - \bar{y}}{2s} \right)}
\end{aligned}$,

which gives me good estimation for $\mu$ (estimate is close to $\bar{y}$), but poor estimation for $\sigma^2$ (estimate not close to $s^2$).

Note: I have also tried this example in different ways by sampling from

$\mu \sim Unif(-10, 10)$ and

$\mu \sim Gamma(shape=2, scale=2)$

and encounter the same problem: $\mu$ is estimated well, while $\sigma^2$ is not.

I believe I am conflating the prior for $\mu$ and the sampling distribution. Please help me understand my error.

Comment: This is somewhat of an advanced book (the book makes you fill in/figure out details), but if you can make it through section 5.1 "Importance Sampling", and optionally, chapter 6 "Rare Event Simulation" of "Stochastic Simulation: Algorithms and Analysis" by Asmussen and Glynn http://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Simulation-Algorithms-Modelling-Probability/dp/038730679Xhttp://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Simulation-Algorithms-Modelling-Probability/dp/038730679X , you will be a master of importance sampling.

Comment: Chapter 9 of http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Monte-Carlo-Methods-Kroese/dp/0470177934 is easier on your brain, but harder on your pocket book. I.e., things are spelled out more, but you'll achieve a lower level of  understanding and insight vs. Rasmussen/Glynn.